# SSH rejecting key file with extended attributes

Tags: macos, permission, ssh

In my .ssh/ directory, when running

```
$ ssh-add dev 
Permissions 0755 for 'dev' are too open.
```

But looking at the dev file

```
$ ls -lF dev
-rw-------@ 1 me  staff  1675 Feb  3 09:37 dev
```

The @ at the end means that there are extended attributes. So I then run

```
$ xattr dev
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms
com.apple.quarantine
```

These have no meaning to me. 
It looks to me that the permissions are what they should be (600)  where is the discrepancy coming from, and how do I fix it?

Comment: These extended attributes are usually attached when you download the file from the Internet with Safari, Chrome or some download manager. I find it curious why you download a private key from the Internet, if that is indeed the case.

Comment: The key came through Skype from another user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your working directory is `~/.ssh/` when you run `ssh-add`, `ls` and `xattr`.

I suspect there is a subdirectory named `dev` (i.e., `~/.ssh/dev/`). Check for it with `ls -lFd dev`.

`ls` normally lists the contents of a directory. Adding the `-d` option lists a directory *as a directory itself*.

Further, I suspect that there is a file, `~/.ssh/dev/dev` which is what `ls -lF` is displaying the information about.

If my suspicion is correct, `xattr dev` displays the extended attributes of the subdirectory named `dev` (not the file `dev/dev`). The directory attributes probably are not the cause of this problem.

If this is confusing, `ls -lFR` might help you see what's happening (the `-R` option recursively lists subdirectories).

Finally, if my suspicion is correct and you're really trying to add a private key identity file named `~/.ssh/dev/dev` to the ssh authentication agent, try `ssh-add dev/dev` (or perhaps better, `ssh-add ~/.ssh/dev/dev`, which should work no matter the permissions of the enclosing directory.

Comment: This was not a sub-directory of ~/.ssh, it was a sub-directory of ~ that had the xattr set and causing the confusion.  That fixed it.  Thanks!